# template struct tag partial specialisation with enable_if or something similar

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am searching for a way to use std::enable_if or something similar for extending an already existing customisation point that would work like `A<T>` specialisation below (just a dummy example):

```
// customisation point structure in external lib
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef T type;
};

//---------------------------------------------
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept bool Floating = std::is_floating_point<T>::value;

// specialisation with enable_if style that doesn't require change to external lib
template<Floating T>
struct A<T>
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>::type, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<A<float>::type, std::vector<float>>::value, "");

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I have the following limitations:

- struct A can not be modified to accept two template parameters `template<typename T, typename = void>` as this structure is defined in an external library
- can't use concepts lite (as some people deemed it necessary to postpone their standardisation to a few years into the future...)
- don't want to mess up the code on all the call sites with something like `A<type_mod<float>>` as that would be ugly and error prone (same goes for macro use)
- don't want to write an external code generator

I doubt that it's possible but I remember people in the past saying that concepts lite are not needed since they can be more or less emulated with meta programming so I hope that somebody can prove me wrong.

Comment: Concepts are not c++14. You might want to retag your question.

Comment: This compiles for me using "g++ -std=c++2a -fconcepts", after adding `#include <type_traits>`. What is the question?

Comment: I understand you don't want to change all the call sites, but you could do something like `using X = std::conditional_t<!std::is_floating_point_v<T>, A<T>, B<T>>`, and then use `X` instead of `A` (where `B` is the "specialization"). Technically, this is very close to a speclization and not error-prone at all.

Comment: *"I don't want to mess up the code on all the call sites with something like A<type_mod<float>>"* Do you use `A<T>`, or it is really a customization point, and so you use `external_library::f(yourType<T>{})` which requires `A<yourType<T>>`.

Comment: @YSC and aschepler read the question - I know that concepts are targeted for C++20 - I need something that works for C++14

Comment: @Jarod42 It's a customisation point - so `yourType<T>` and the library internally uses `A<yourType<T>>` to get the type that it should use in some cases (think of it as serialisation/deserialisation type that can handle your type)

Comment: @fdan The code above is just a dummy example of what I need but without concepts - `struct A` is an already defined customisation point inside an external library so you as a library user are not supposed to instantiate it but just provide an overload that defines a type that will be in some cases instantiated inside that library to handle your provided type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure I understand the question correctly, are you looking for something equivalent to the code you've posted, but using only C++14 (without concepts)?

I think the first limitation you mentioned ("struct A cannot be modified to accept two template parameters") is the biggest problem.  I'm not aware of any way to specialize an existing, single-argument template for a whole "class" of types at once (e.g. floating-point types) without using concepts.

**So I think the strict answer to your question is, "No, it's not possible."**

If you could modify the first declaration of A, then it would be a lot easier.  And personally, I feel that sometimes the best answer to questions that start with "I can't modify this external library" is, "Go and find out how to modify it, then come back and ask your question again."

**I provide one idea for an alternative solution below, but there's too much information missing from your question to say whether it will work for you.**

I assume that this external library pulls in some header that you provide in order to see your specialization, and that you'll be recompiling the library whenever you change that header.  (If that's not the case, please edit your question to explain the situation a bit better.)

In that same header where you want to put your specialization, you might consider using some old-school preprocessor trickery as a workaround.  It's ugly, and you have to be careful about the order of your `#include` statements, but it might get the job done for you:

```
// customisation point structure in external lib
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef T type;
};

//---------------------------------------------
#include <vector>

template<typename T, bool is_float>
struct Av2impl
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Av2impl<T, true>
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Av2
{
    typedef typename Av2impl<T, std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type type;
};

// force all code after this point to use Av2 instead of A
#define A Av2

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>::type, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<A<float>::type, std::vector<float>>::value, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Presumably the external library has some template code that uses `typename A<T>::type;` - so you would somehow need to get the hack into effect within the external library's headers, but without letting it define a conflicting class template. And if the library isn't header only, hope none of its non-template, explicitly instantiated, or explicitly specialized definitions involve a specialization of `A` in their mangled names.

Comment: @John Lindgren I know how to modify it intrusively `template<typename T, typename = void>A{...}` so the question was how not to do that and still get the non intrusive concept style without concepts. The issue with your solution is as aschepler noted that the hack would have to go inside the external lib so in that case I'd just change the base template in there and recompile it.

Comment: @DomenVrankar I made some assumptions about your situation based on your question, and it sounds like those weren't correct.  I edited my question to clarify those assumptions.  Next time, I'll be sure to ask for clarification before trying to help out.

Comment: @JohnLindgren You've shown an interesting solution don't get me wrong. It's just that I've been searching for a clean solution that wouldn't make our code harder to maintain and external code to become part of our maintenance burden. I tried to dumb down the question to the bare essential but in doing so I didn't even notice that I didn't provide enough info. Since no other solutions were presented I'll choose the "No, it's not possible" as the answer. Thanks for confirming my suspicion.